# How to solve the error while installing firebase tools with npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm

i am try to install npm firebase tools but its throwing me the errors, pleases solve it.

C:\Users\GLOBAL TECH>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\GLOBAL TECH\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-28T13_14_34_727Z-debug-0.log

please solve it? and how to connect with firebase tools in npm